# Ocaml : function that two integers and returns the list of all integers in the range

Tags: ocaml

This function takes two integers and returns the list of all integers in the range [a,b]

This is the solution that I wrote.

```
let rec range_rec l a b = 
  if (a=b) then l@[b]
  else range_rec (l@[a], a+1, b);;

let range a b = range_rec [] a b;;
```

I'm hitting an error "Error: This expression has type int list * int * int but an expression was expected of type int". Can someone throw some light on why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you think "loop" was going to do?

Comment: Sorry Chris. That was a typo. I was trying to make it more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
let rec range_rec l a b = 
  if a = b then l @ [b]
  else range_rec (l @ [a]) (a + 1) b;;

let range a b = range_rec [] a b;;
```

What I've done:

1. Changed `loop` to `range_rec`
2. Changed `(l@[a], a+1, b)` to `(l @ [a]) (a + 1) b`. The first is a triplet and the second is 3 arguments to a curried function.
3. Notice that `if (a = b) then` can be written as `if a = b then`.

Last, the function can be made more efficient by using `::` instead of `@` by looping "backwards". For example like gasche have shown.

Comment: Sorry. The 1st change was actually a typo. But it wasnt there in the actual program. 
You mean to say, I had to have additional braces surrounding (a+1) and I had to remove the braces surrounding the 3 arguments? Why is that?

Comment: @Sunday Something ala `let rec f (a, b) =` is a function which takes a tuple in Ocaml. Where `let rec f a b =` is really a function, which returns a function. It is not like C-like languages. See "Functions" in http://files.metaprl.org/doc/ocaml-book.pdf or http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/ocaml-ora-book.pdf - It is really difficult to explain the type-system and functions in short space :)

Comment: Thanks Lasse. I cant give reputation to your answer cuz I'm a newbie. I hope someone gives it.

Answer (score 6):

The `l @ [elem]` operation is terrible from a performance perspective : as `a @ b` is linear in the length of `a`, adding an element to the end of list is linear in the length of the list, making your whole `range_rec` definition quadratic in `|b-a|`. The way to go is to change your code so that you can use the constant-time `elem::l` operation instead.

```
let rec range a b =
  if a > b then []
  else a :: range (a + 1) b
```

You may make additional optimizations such as making it tail-recursive, but at least the complexity of this solution is right.

Comment: Good advice, but you haven't answered the question.

Comment: Thanks Gasche. Any idea why my function was bumping into error?

Comment: @Chris: sometimes one is interested in answers that go beyong what was explicitely asked. lasseespeholt already proposed a fix for the syntactic mistake. If you're interested into giving a detailed explanation of why `f (x, y, z)` and `f x y z` are typed differently, please do.

Comment: Thanks Gasche. I cant give reputation to your answer cuz I'm a newbie. I hope someone gives it

Answer (score 1):

To improve on the solution already suggested by gasche, this can be made tail-recursive.

```
let int_range a b =
  let rec int_range_rec l a b =
    if a > b then l
    else int_range_rec (b :: l) a (b - 1)
  in (int_range_rec [] a b);;
```